# how to play EPUB Media Overlays 3.0

Tags: overlay, media, smil

Is it missing in all tutorials of media-overlay or am i missing that ?

To make MediaOverlay, all tutorial say that we should:

1. in xhtml wich contain the texte;

   ```
   <header><h1><span class="audio" id="c001s0000">Chapter 1. Loomings.</span></h1></header>
   <p>
   <span class="audio" id="c001s0001">Call me Ishmael.</span> 
   <span class="audio" id="c001s0002">Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.</span>
   ```

   ...
2. in associated .smil;

   ```
   <seq id="id1" epub:textref="chapter_001.xhtml" epub:type="bodymatter chapter">
   <par id="sentence0">
       <text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0000"/>
       <audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:21" clipEnd="0:00:28"/>
   </par>
   <par id="sentence1">
       <text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0001"/>
       <audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:28" clipEnd="0:00:30"/>
   </par>
   <par id="sentence2">
          <text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0002"/>
       <audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:30" clipEnd="0:00:44"/>
   </par>
   ```
3. the audio(.mp4) is saved where it should be. (audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4)

4/ association between .xhtml  and .smil is done in opf file, section :

```
<item id="xchapter_001" href="chapter_001.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" media-overlay="chapter_001_overlay"/>
<item id="chapter_001_overlay" href="chapter_001_overlay.smil" media-type="application/smil+xml"/>
<item id="xchapter_002" href="chapter_002.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" media-overlay="chapter_002_overlay"/>
<item id="chapter_002_overlay" href="chapter_002_overlay.smil" media-type="application/smil+xml"/>
```

ok, we are done of all that, but the question is how to play media overlay? how to start audio file and highlight the text? What this button "start reading" of iBooks application do? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an awfully late reply, but for others to know, the "Start Reading" button will take the items sequentially from the smil file and work on them. So the very first action would be to play the audio file starting at 0:00:21 and highlight "Call me Ishmael" from the text.

Answer (score -1):

Please add a Style in your css (stylesheet):

```
    .-epub-media-overlay-active {
        color: #dc4c37;
    }
```